Spring Boot mapping MonthDay using ConfigurationProperties into Map
Suppose there's a @ConfigurationProperties class in Spring.
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ConfigProps {

    Map<Month, MonthDay> daysMap = new EnumMap<>(Month.class);

}

In my application.yml file, I'd like something like that to work (map to the above field).
daysMap:
  JANUARY: 02-JAN
  MARCH: 15-DEC
  ...

Unfortunately, I receive an exception while mapping:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'daysMap.january' to java.time.MonthDay:

    Property: daysMap.january
    Value: "02-JAN"
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml]
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.time.MonthDay (caused by java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '02-JAN' could not be parsed at index 0)

Action:

Update your application's configuration

How do I correctly map it?

The MonthDay has a specific format --MM-dd to specify the month and day

A month-day in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as --12-03.

So provide the month and date in the format in application.yml
daysMap:
  JANUARY: --01-02
  MARCH: --12-15


I know and understand that, but that does not answer my question. The problem is that I'd like to read it in different format.

If you want to convert custom string into MonthDay you need to create custom converter for properties.
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class MonthDayConverter implements Converter<String, MonthDay> {

    @Override
    public MonthDay convert(String source) {
       // TODO: Implement logic here
    }
}

Here my example in kotlin.
application.yml
I wrap your example into map key, because i don't know how to get root props.
daysmap:
  map:
    JANUARY: '--02-01'
    DECEMBER: '--12-12'

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "daysmap")
@Configuration
class ConfigClass {
    lateinit var map: Map<Month, MonthDay>
    
}

@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
class MonthDayConverter: Converter<String, MonthDay> {

    override fun convert(source: String): MonthDay? {
        // Just return now. For testing this is enough
        return MonthDay.now()
    }

}

Test
@SpringBootTest
class ConfigClassTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var configClass: ConfigClass

    @Test
    fun configPropsTest() {
        val expected = mapOf(
            Month.JANUARY to MonthDay.now(),
            Month.DECEMBER to MonthDay.now()
        )

        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, configClass.map)
    }
}


This will not work as the field is not of MonthDay class, but Map<Month, MonthDay> class, thus it will not use this logic.

Your ConfigProps declare Map<Month, MonthDay> property. When spring try to create object of class MonthDay it will execute custom converter where you place logic. If you place in converter return MonthDay.now() your ConfigProps should contain map with months and MonthDay.now().

@IceMajor, see my additional example with the test. I think this is the correct behavior you expected.
